# Subclassing UIView in Swift - error

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift

I have a file called MyView.swift that just looks like this:

```
class MyView : UIView {

}
```

I also have a MyView.xib file with a view with class set to MyView.

In a view controller I have this:

```
var myView: MyView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as MyView
    self.myView.frame = frame;
    self.view.addSubview(self.myView);

}
```

I get this error:

```
MyView? does not have a member named 'frame'
```

Why? MyView is a subclass of UIView...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to implicit unwrap that optional, or use optional chaining.

```
self.myView!.frame = frame
```

Or utilize optional chaining.

```
self.myView?.frame = frame 
// can do this now in Swift.
```

The first option is more dangerous because when you forcefully unwrap an optional, and it is `nil`, a runtime error will occur.

**Edit** I apologize, optional chaining is not the right tool for the job here. It is the right tool if you wanted to query the value of the frame. Alternatively, you could use the `if let` syntax.

```
if let optionalView = self.myView {
    var queriedFrame = optionalView.frame
}
```

Comment: self.myView?.frame = frame gives me "Cannot assign to the result of this expression"

Comment: Optional chaining is for rvalues only — you can't assign to an optional-chain expression. You can assign to the force-unwrapped reference, or assign inside an `if-let` block.

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not sure what the queriedFrame line is about. If I replace that with `optionalView.frame = frame` it works.

Answer (score 3):

`MyView` is a subclass of `UIView`, but `MyView?` is an Optional which has only two possible cases:

**(1)** it is `nil`, or

**(2)** it holds a wrapped value of type `MyView`

...and in either case, it is still an Optional, which means it doesn't have a member named 'frame'  :)  though if it's holding a wrapped value of `MyView` then that wrapped value does!

To get at that wrapped value (assuming it has one) it is necessary for you to either explicitly unwrap it with `!` or for you to use Optional Binding (`if let`) in accessing its properties.